Как добавить файл в автозагрузку с правами администратора и повышенным приоритетом запуска?
Возможно, вопрос прозвучит несколько необычно, однако существует ли способ добавить, скажем, файл C:/App.exe в автозагрузку таким образом, чтобы он запускался автоматически при любых условиях (включая безопасный режим) и всегда с правами администратора? Ранее я использовал привязку к процессам Winlogon, подключая файл к explorer.exe, sihost.exe или userinit32.exe, но оказалось, что эти процессы инициируются без привилегий администратора.
Хотелось бы уточнить, в манифесте моего приложения предусмотрен запуск исключительно с правами администратора, то есть пользователь предоставляет необходимые привилегии при запуске. Однако проблема в том, что я не могу сохранить эти права после перезагрузки системы.

Можно запускать командный файл, пользуясь автозагрузкой, а в командном файле уже устанавливать административный режим, потом уже в этом режиме запускать приложение.

Вы наверное не читали вопрос, если просто добавить файл в автозагрузку, в безопасном режиме он запускаться не будет

Я читал. Слишком много хочется. Такие фокусы - вопрос безопасности, ни один из разработчиков ОС такое не приветствует. Безопасный режим потому и безопасный, что отключаются все фокусы, которые могут навредить системе.

Ну а сам по себе вопрос тоже тот ещё. Зачем сидеть без конца и края в безопасном режиме? Я системщик, настраиваю софт на компах. Уже забыл когда последний раз была необходимость этот режим запускать. Настолько редкое явление, что не стоит трат энергии на него.

Только что пришла в голову довольно простая, но агрессивная стратегия — отключение UAC с помощью редактирования реестра: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System необходимо установить значение ключа EnableLUA в 0. Может не самое лучшее решение, но способа лучше я не нашёл

Это из другой оперы. И ковыряться в реестре тоже ни к чему. Эта настройка есть в Панели управления.
